# For dfuse API’s `get_action_traces`，is parameter `with_inline_traces` false by default?

Tags: dfuse

My question is: In dfuse, when I use the  `get_action_traces` API，is parameter `with_inline_traces` false by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `with_inline_traces` is indeed `false` by default. Same thing with `with_ramops` and `with_dtrxops`, they are set to `false` if not specified.